# File uploader for adminhtml product page

Tags: product, adminhtml, uicomponent, file-upload

Do anyone has tested and well working file uploader code for Magento 2.1.1? There are a few tutorials, but I am not sure which one would be suitable for this Magento version.

Adding such a fields would be the best in custom tab. What is more, are available some ui components to achieve that (I haven't found any in form modifiers) - adding multiple files would be nice.

What with upload file - should be uploaded in path like `p/a/pathtofile` manner?

I was trying to resue downloadable widget from downloadable product but my files are not uploaded. Also I have seen this [one](http://blog.mageworx.com/2016/08/an-easy-way-to-add-a-fieldset-with-fields-to-the-ui-form/) and I was trying to use modifiers from Downloadable module, but it also doesn't work for me.